# Problems with logical operators

Tags: logical-operators

I have this code:

```
int i = -6, a= -06;
while (a--, a+=2)
 {
    a-=2;
    ++i;
    printf("OK\n");
    if(!i)
    break;
 }
 int b= -0xe;
 b+= a && a++;
 printf("%d %d\n", a,b);
```

I can't understand why at the end b is equal to -13 and not to -25. a is equal to -11 and everything is ok here, but why b is -13?

Comment: What language is this supposed to be…?

Answer (score 1):

before evaluating the statement  **b+= a && a++;** 
the actual values of a and b are b=-14 and a=-12. The compiler will evaluate this expression like this **b=b+(a&&a++)**. So, **(a&&a++)** will return 1 that's why you are getting -13 as the value of b.

Answer (score 0):

The `a && a++` returns `-12` because the compiler will evaluate this expression like this `(a&&a); a=a+1;`, the `-12` in binary equals to `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110100`, The `&&` operator **And** each bit with itself. The `(a&&a)` calculate like this

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110100 
&&
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110100
_________________________________________________________________
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110100
```

So `(a&&a) = a` and the statement `b+= a && a++;` evaluate as `b=b+(-12); a++`

Comment: `&&` does not do bitwise computations in most languages.

Comment: @aschepler Your right but in the question language not specified. This result just because it happens